# 2-way syncing content between Facebook page and website

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, synchronization, feed

I'm planning on launching a website and an accompanying facebook page. Although each of these 'sites' will have their own goal, I'd like to have a 2-way sync set-up for part of the user generated content on my site, such that:

1. Content published on my site (by editors, or users) that satisfies some criteria are pushed to the wall of the accompanying facebook page
2. The other way around: content published on the facebook page wall by users, is pushed to my website. (I want to be in complete control of how to format, display, annotate that content, so I'm not looking for some ready-made widgets)

**For 2.** I'm pretty sure I can poll for a newsfeed or channel of the specific facebook page at regular intervals, but I'm wondering if a tighter integration is possible, i.e: pushing the changed content(delta's, river whatever you want to call it) to a dedicated rest-endpoint from  which my website can consume the contents or something.

**For 1**. I need an automated way to post to the wall of the facebook page I own. Preferrably with the user-credentials (if okayed by the user) if that user was logged-in on my site through Facebook, or otherwise with some fallback credential, e.g: my own facebook credentials.

Just looking for some pointers where to start looking in the vast Developer Facebook resources, or, better yet, some libraries (prefferably Node.js, but others are okay to look at architecture)  that take care of some of the plumbing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  You can post on page with different ways

- as a user : You need user access token and he should be a fan of the page or If your fan page allows wall posts from any user in its settings.
- as a page : You need [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/)

  You can get page access token and extend it for long time and store it in DB. You can use it 60 days.

FYI:
[Extended access token](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)
[Tutorial](http://www.sergiy.ca/post-on-facebook-app-wall-and-fan-page-wall-as-admin/)

2) Using graph API you can pull at regular intervals. There is a real time notification system also but it very limited for pages ([its not useful for your case](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18048)).

FYI:  [Real Time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)

Comment: "as a user : You need user access token and he should be a fan of the page or If your fan page allows wall posts from any user in its settings". If a user was to be logged in on my site using facebook, would I already have access to the 'user access token'? In other words, once logged in with facebook, could I sync a comment posted on my site to my facebook page without requiring extra okaying from the user? I don't want to interrupt the commenting-flow, with facebook popups, etc. (Of course, I will give users a checkbox-option whether their comment will be synced to the facebook page)

Comment: Yes you can do. check extended permissions .

Comment: It seems RT-updates CAN be used for pages: see comment 34 for the gist (which summarizes the stuff before) http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18048#c34 : "you need to set object='user', fields='feed' and include_values=true in
the subscription. You also need to ensure that the page has installed the application. Once that's done you will start getting updates when the page's feed is updated".... thanks for the pointers!